# Sort records from an input box by a project status into specific areas of one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to organize data by project status, into three different sections within a single worksheet with separating headers, that is fed from an input form. My input form is an add record button that is supposed to feed three total worksheets. (Trying to search "Inputs" to organize data that would then input into "Tracking Log")

I have tried to use an if statement to search the original input page first for project status, that would then organize the input data below the headers in a separate worksheet.

```
Dim al As Worksheet
Dim vc As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim b As String

Set vc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs")
Set al = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking Log")

x = al.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Filter inputs by project status into their project section (Closed)

        If vc.Cells.Value = "CLOSED PROJECTS" or vc.Cells.Value = "On Hold" or vc.cells.value = "Open" Then 

'al.Unprotect "Welcome123"

    al.Range("A" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("B" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("C" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("D" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("E" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("F" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("G" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("H" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("I" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("J" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("K" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("L" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("M" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("N" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("O" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("P" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("Q" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("R" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("S" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("T" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("U" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("V" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    al.Range("W" & x + 1).Value = Me.xxxx.Value
    End If
```

Trying to organize the inputs by the project status to be under the appropriate header within the worksheet. (Ex. Project Status = Closed should go under the Closed Project header, same for Open project, and on hold)

Comment: What is your question or issue with your code? Your if statement should be on a single line, with only one then `If vc.Cells.Value = "CLOSED PROJECTS" Or vc.Cells.Value = "On Hold" Or vc.Cells.Value = "Open" Then`

Comment: If you are going to use `Or`, you will only need one Then

Comment: @RobertTodar The question I have regarding my code is what should I include after the "then" to make sure the information from the form is inputted into the correct fields based on the project status that is fixed.

Comment: @GMalc Thank you for pointing that out. I'm still new to VBA.

Comment: In your, if statement you have `vc.Cells.Value` which is referring to all the cells in the sheet. This could cause your program to run out of memory. Is there a specific cell reference where one of these values should be at?

Comment: @RobertTodar Yes, there is a column ("D") in the first page "Inputs" that should have that fixed value.

Comment: If you are only using a single cell as the reference in `vc`, then you need to clarify the cell reference, e.g. `vc.Range("D#").Value`

Comment: Are trying organize the data from your `Sheets("Inputs")` into `Sheets("Tracking Log ")` under individual row headers for each project status `CLOSED PROJECTS`, `On Hold`, `Open`? If so then using an if statement is not going to work.

Comment: If you are trying to move and separate existing data from one sheet to another, it is easy using filter and copy visible cells. If you want to write the `UserForm` inputs directly into the correct project status on the second worksheet, it can be accomplished by modifying the code for the `add record button` you are using, It depends on what you actually want to accomplish

Comment: @GMalc I am trying to add a condition before the 'add record button' allows values to be input into the sheet and from there sort into one of the three headers. I am not trying to move any existing data at this point.

Comment: An example would help understand what your are tying to accomplish.

Comment: @GMalcWhen I press the "Add Record Button" the inputs from the data form would then populate the following forms. My idea is that prior to the inputting of data into the appropriate worksheet, there is a condition that looks at the project status value from the data input form and from there input into the right area of the worksheet based on the headers value. The headers are set at a fixed amount of rows away from each other (30-50) and the inputted records would then be inputted in those sections. I apologize if this does not make sense.